# How to generate color from colormap in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, colormap

In Javascript, I would like to generate a hex color based on the temperature ranging from -30°C to +50°C in a colormap such as that in the figure below.
[example colormap for temperature: deep blue is -30°C, deep red +50°C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ2n0.png)

My Javascript code is included in a .html file between tags `<script></script>`
Is it possible?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Right now your question is unclear. I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow and read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer. These resources exist to help you have a good experience here, so please use them. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use hue from hsl color and scale it to temperature and then transform hsl color to hex value.

```js
function hslToHex(h, s, l) {
  l /= 100;
  const a = s * Math.min(l, 1 - l) / 100;
  const f = n => {
    const k = (n + h / 30) % 12;
    const color = l - a * Math.max(Math.min(k - 3, 9 - k, 1), -1);
    return Math.round(255 * color).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');  
  };
  return `#${f(0)}${f(8)}${f(4)}`;
}

const scale = {
  min: {value: -30, hue: 1},
  max: {value: 50, hue: 245}
} 

function temperatureToColor(temp){
   temp = Math.min(scale.max.value, Math.max(scale.min.value, temp));
   const range = scale.max.value - scale.min.value;
   const hueRange = scale.max.hue - scale.min.hue;
   const value =  (temp - scale.min.value) / range;
   const hue = scale.max.hue - hueRange * value;
   
   return hslToHex(hue, 100, 50)
}


(function test(){
   const container = document.getElementById("container")
   const temps = [-40, -30,-20,-10,0,10,15,20,25,30,40,41,42,43,44,45,50,60]
   
   for(let temp of temps){
      const box = document.createElement("div");
      box.textContent = temp;
      box.style.background = temperatureToColor(temp)
      container.append(box)
   }
})()
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#container > div {
  width: 10px
  height: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"/>
```